# delete or change status of post or comment php,sql

Tags: php, sql

I'm creating a social network,

Question:
In a post, anytime an user wants to delete this post or a comment.
Do I need to delete it from the database or just change its status in order it doesnt appear anymore and give the user the feeling its already deleted?

Example:

```
<button>Delete this comment</button>
```

SQL

```
    DELETE FROM table_posts WHERE...
```

OR

```
    UPDATE table_posts SET status="deleted" WHERE...
```

Which one is more suitable?

Answer (score 2):

*It depends...*

There are two cases:

- If you delete the record:

  - It will be removed from the database and you will not be able to retrieve it.
  - You will have a database that takes up less space.
  - Probably the search on the records will be faster, because there will be less records to search.
- If you update and set the status to "deleted":

  - You will have this record in your database and may (or may not) display it to the user.
  - Usually this case is useful when you want to have a log with all user messages.
  - This will require more disk space.
  - Probably the search of the records will not be as fast as if they had been deleted, as there are more records to search.

What is the best? This will depend on your business rule.

Comment: ok, thank you for your insight, I would like to avoid using the sql function `delete from ...` to avoid any type of vulnerability of the database in case an sql injection...so if for some reason this happens it could be deleted all the database records...a risk I dont want to deal with. But I'm not sure if chanching the status to `deleted` is the way to go, for some reasons you have described above..your answer is pretty helpful.